# Reference to TextView object from nested class

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming and probably I don;t understand Java very well yet, so i got this problem with my program.
Every time I press button on my menu I get the **java.lang.NullPointerException**. 
Is there any way to reference to this TextView object and change its text when **item2** on menu is clicked?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MainActivity.this.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
        MainActivity.this.tv.setText("aaa");
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

EDIT:
mymenu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_week"
    android:title="Option 1"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_month"
    android:title="Option 2"/>

</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tekst1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: well follow the answers below

Comment: What "nested class"? I can't see one.

Comment: I meant 'onOptionsItemSelected'. So I understand that is a sublass, not nested class.

Comment: @user1848188 : No, `onOptionsItemSelected` is a method of the `Activity` class itself. It's not a class of any sort. Also, because you have declared `tv` as an instance member of `MainActivity` (in other words in the main body of `MainActivity`), you don't have to access it using `MainActivity.this.tv`. You only have to do that if you are accessing from `inner` or `anonymous` classes - you can simply access it using `tv.setText("aaa")` for example. Not a criticism, I just wanted to point those things out. Happy learning. :)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the layout BEFORE retrieving the element.

Just replace

```
MainActivity.this.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

By

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
MainActivity.this.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
```

The findViewById method tries to find an element (from an ID) inside the hierarchy of the view. That's why you need to load this hierarchy (from the XML file) before! Otherwise you search in an empty hierarchy of views

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm not sure why it's working now, but thank you!

Comment: Well, that explains it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your `onCreate` method to this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MainActivity.this.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst1);
}
```

You have to reference your views after doing `setContentView` for your Activty.

Answer (score 0):

By using the setContentView(int layoutResId) method android platform is creating all the view objects contained in your layout xml file provided to the setContentView(int layoutResId) method. This means that before the setContentView(int layoutResId) method is called the findViewById(int resId) method will return null for any view references in the layout, causing some potential NullpointerExceptions. To avoid these errors it's a good habit to place the setContentView(int layoutResId) method call at the very top of the onCreate() method.

Check this out : http://www.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/